# Using suppression formula in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am attempting to set up a report which displays a list grouped by cases, where each case can have one, none, or many flags returned in the details section:

```
Case 11-30001
  Flag A
  Flag C

Case 11-30004
  Flag B
  Flag D

Case 11-30005
  Flag B

Case 11-30006
```

What I am trying to do, is use a suppression formula, so that the case (group #1) number is suppressed if one certain flag is present for any given case.  I have tried {table.flag} = 'Flag B', which didn't seem to work, and even set up a running total field to store the number 1 if Flag B was present, and use that in the suppression formula, and neither seems to work.  Is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the value of {table.flag} is a string, then you need to use double quotes: `{table.flag} = "Flag B"`. The key is to put the exact field value in double quotes. So make sure there are no preceding or trailing spaces! If you are only trying to suppress the group header, put the suppression in the group header. If you want both the header and the detail suppressed, put it in both sections.